# Access Linked table Queries

Tags: ms-access

I am just wondering if I am able to run a query on a linked table in access 2010?

I tried importing all the data into the same database but very quickly hits the 2Gb limit and am not able to use an SQL server or any form of SQLite database :(

Comment: Of course. You could have simply tried it...?

Comment: *am not able to use an SQL server or any form of SQLite database*...but you can use other MS Access databases to link tables from!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can run queries on linked tables in your Access 2010.
No need to import tables (linking is enough), querying linked tables will process the query where the access database is located then passing the filters in your where clause to you original server to retreive the results. 
This is relatively useful in your cases when querying huger sized data that exceeds Access capacities.
But performance relatively depends on how good is your where clause and the ammount of data(records) to be processed and filtered on your linked tables.

Comment: You may be right in general but in my experience Access seems to insist on downloading all primary key values before submitting a WHERE-restricted query for just the values it wants. With more than a few thousand rows this means unnecessarily downloading megabytes of primary key values every time eg. a particular form is opened to display one record.